# SQLiteException when i try to check that the table is empty

Tags: android, sqlite

When I try to check if the **recent** table is empty I get SQLiteException. How can i fix this trouble?

This is my sqlitehelper class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class MySQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private final static int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private final static String DATABASE_NAME = "LyricsFinderDB";

    public MySQLiteOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        // SQL statement to create recent table
        String CREATE_RECENT_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE recent ( " +
                "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                "name INTEGER)";
        database.execSQL(CREATE_RECENT_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS recent");
        this.onCreate(database);
    }

    public boolean isRecentTableEmpty() {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM recent", null);

        if(cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            cursor.close();
            return false;
        }
        cursor.close();
        database.close();
        return true;
    }
}
```

In MainActivity I use it like in this code:

```
if(mySQLiteOpenHelper.isRecentTableEmpty()) {
            //...do something
        } else {
            //...do something
        }
```

This is the exception that I got after running app:

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: recent (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM recent
```

It throws in this line:

```
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM recent", null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table doesn't exist. You can catch the SQLiteException exception and if it triggers create the table and return TRUE (i.e. table is empty). Something like this

```
try {
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM recent", null);
}
catch(SQLiteException e) {
    onCreate(database);
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: I know that the table doesn't exists but why? In MainActivity in onCreate() method i create my database mySQLiteOpenHelper = new MySQLiteOpenHelper(MainActivity.this);

Comment: onCreate is only called if the database does not exist. Maybe for it it exists (from previous code testing) but it doesn't have the table. In that case, it is not created either. You can either delete it manually or bump up the version id so that you force an onUpdate call.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly use Exception.

It's look like your table doesn't exist.